# Too many <br> under table/content

Tags: css, wordpress

My problem is i am getting extra `<br>` tag after every line and if i will put any table then there will be huge gap(so many `<br>` tags) and from last 5 days i am trying to solve this problem and i did a big google search for it too but still did not get the answer..

Here is [the site](http://www.greatplainscollege.ca/tlg/academic-advising/) where i am getting too many`<br>` tags

edited :- which code part i should show as m not sure by which code i can solve this problem so please tell me and i will show you that code..

**Note: Please read before marking as duplicate.**

I have done these things to get the solution but i did not get answer please have look at them.

I have this code

```
remove_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop');
```

I also read a lot topics on stackoverflow and did what they said but still did not get answer.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );    
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

then I have used few plugin too to remove extra `<br>`

```
1. Text Control(wordpress plugin)
2. TinyMCE Advanced(wp plugin)
3. Disable wpautop(wp plugin)
```

and many more but still extra `<br>` is there. I dont know how to remove them.

I added few code line in `functions.php`, I did editing with text editor.tiny mce. and all but still no sucess. Even i tried to play with css and removing margin, padding, line height but still i cant get rid of so please, please help me that how to remove those unwanted `<br>`.

Please don't give negative marks to this as I have seen the same post on stackoverflow but I did not get solution from them so please help me in this case and I hope this time I wont get banned by negative marks but I will get solution.

Comment: Show your code, show your resultant output you want to achieve. Also post the scenario when you face this issue on adding new post or updating an old one?

Comment: Sorry I didn't have privileges to comment.
Try to remove elements in your page until you understand WHAT is adding all those 
tags. Once you've found it, then you might be able to inspect the code that generate it and fix it. It is hard to find out what exactly creates all those tags without the source code.

Comment: What plugins are you using and what theme are you using? Are you using the visual or the code editor to add your table?

Comment: @ alarmed..i have added name of plugin which i have used and by both way m putting table(visual and copied from excel) but still getting gap.And m also using MCE Table Buttons wp plugin to insert table but i have also deactivated and checked but still i have this problem :(

Comment: @Luca i did..but still din get the issue which is generated a lot br tags..:( spent so many days but..:( and m using ikantam theme

Comment: ty for help..i got the ans at my own..